# Upgrade to 5.54 failed

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Grouping by month in 5.54's Search Kit is something I noticed & would like, so I launched the upgrade on my test system to 5.54. However the upgrade from 5.53.0 to 5.54 failed as follows:

"SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id` FROM civicrm_user_job a WHERE (`a`.`expires_date` < "20221010092632") AND (`a`.`is_template` = "0") [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.is_template' in 'where clause']"

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /home/acivior1/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 944

- DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown

Sure enough, table civicrm_user_job doesn't have column is_template. This is a Drupal 7 system. Looking at another 5.53 system - it does have this column.  After restoring back to 5.53 table civicrm_user_job does **not** have this column.  The test system was only create many a year back whereas the system with the column was created 9 years ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the column was added on June 9 to 5.51 (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23679), and then 5.51 became the RC on June 10, so depending on how your test site evolved it's very likely you would have missed that upgrade step since it was added in so late. You probably also want to check civicrm_queue.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting release candidates because of Search Kit so that was probably the cause.  Glad it was just that.