# web import fails because of empty "name" column in "civicrm_user_job" table

Tags: import, data-import, drupal-9, csv

Drupal 9x, CiviCRM  5.56.0. Getting "Cannot execute queue "user_job_XXX". There is no associated UserJob." while contacts import from csv ( civicrm/import/contact?reset=1 ) Perhaps related to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42771/upgrade-to-5-54-failed).
Have had to manually add the job name ( from corresponded civicrm_queue ) to make  it work. However it would be nice to understand why this is happening: missing DB trigger because of unfinished update? Any word of advice please?

Comment: All that userjob stuff is pretty new so might be a bug. If you get the same error on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org then you should file an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues

Comment: But if you mean your upgrade to 5.56 didn't complete and so the database tables are incomplete, then would need to go find the stack trace in ConfigAndLog from the upgrade fail.